# Crop Image library Android

Tags: android

does some one has already attemted use this `https://github.com/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper`
library ? could please to send your own github or explain me how to setup. I've setted up but always graddle failing . because I've attempted to setup this library
but in gradle syncning time always I'm getting build faild .

please without bulling or hating

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.CanHub:Android-Image-Cropper:3.3.4.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper/3.3.4/Android-Image-Cropper-3.3.4.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper/3.3.4/Android-Image-Cropper-3.3.4.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper/3.3.4/Android-Image-Cropper-3.3.4.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1s
19 actionable tasks: 18 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

Because of updating ArctixFox Android Studio allproject {repositories } not exist anymore  `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }`  whe should I add this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error you are getting, it seems like `Gradle` is unable to resolve `CanHub` dependency. It could be most probably because you may not have included the `jitpack` repository in your project's `build.gradle` (not module's `build.gradle`).

To add `jitpack` to the repositories, add `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` to your project level `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
     repositories {
       ....
       maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
     }
  }
```

---

> Because of updating ArctixFox Android Studio allproject {repositories } not exist anymore

`allprojects` is still available to use in project-level `build.gradle`, but now it's not get added by default to the new project, and you would get a `GradleScriptException` after adding it, as the build is configured to prefer `settings.gradle` over it.

`setting.gradle` now includes a `dependencyResolutionManagement`. If you want to add new *repositories* using `allprojects` you have to comment or remove `dependencyResolutionManagement`, or you can just add your repositories to the `repositories` block of `dependencyResolutionManagement` in `settings.gradle`

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you but.   'allprojects {
     repositories {
       ....
       maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
     }
  }' not exist anymore in ArcticFox AndroidStudio . therefore I don't know where to add maven